# Can I ignore exhaustive-deps warning for useContext?

Tags: reactjs, react-context, use-effect, use-reducer

In my react-typescript application, I am trying to use a context provider that encapsulates properties and methods and exposes them for a consumer:

```
const StockPriceConsumer: React.FC = () => {
  const stockPrice = useContext(myContext);
  let val = stockPrice.val;
  useEffect(() => {
    stockPrice.fetch();
  }, [val]);
  return <h1>{val}</h1>;
};
```

The problem is the following warning:

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'stockPrice'. Either
>   include it or remove the dependency
>   array. *eslint(react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)*

To me it does not make any sense to include the `stockPrice` (which is basically the provider's API) to the dependencies of useEffect. It only makes sense to include actual value of stock price to prevent infinite calls of useEffect's functions.

Question: **Is there anything wrong with the approach I am trying to use or can I just ignore this warning?**

---

The provider:

```
interface StockPrice {
  val: number;
  fetch: () => void;
}

const initialStockPrice = {val: NaN, fetch: () => {}};

type Action = {
  type: string;
  payload: any;
};

const stockPriceReducer = (state: StockPrice, action: Action): StockPrice => {
  if (action.type === 'fetch') {
    return {...state, val: action.payload};
  }
  return {...state};
};

const myContext = React.createContext<StockPrice>(initialStockPrice);

const StockPriceProvider: React.FC = ({children}) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(stockPriceReducer, initialStockPrice);
  const contextVal  = {
    ...state,
    fetch: (): void => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        dispatch({type: 'fetch', payload: 200});
      }, 200);
    },
  };
  return <myContext.Provider value={contextVal}>{children}</myContext.Provider>;
};
```

Comment: rule of thumb: the feeling that you want to ignore `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` == your side effects are fighting against [Thinking in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html) Step 4: Identify Where Your State Should Live

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to control the whole fetching logic from the provider:

```
const StockPriceProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [price, setPrice] = React.useState(NaN);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPrice = () => {
      window.fetch('http...')
       .then(response => response.json())
       .then(data => setPrice(data.price))
    }
    const intervalId = setInterval(fetchPrice, 200)
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId)
  }, [])

  return <myContext.Provider value={price}>{children}</myContext.Provider>;
};

const StockPriceConsumer = () => {
  const stockPrice = useContext(myContext);
  return <h1>{stockPrice}</h1>;
};
```

---

...as a solution to a couple of problems from the original appproach:

1. do you really want to fetch only so long as `val` is different? if the stock price will be the same between 2 renders, the useEffect won't execute.
2. do you need to create a new `fetch` method every time `<StockPriceProvider>` is rendered? That is not suitable for dependencies of useEffect indeed.

   - if both are OK, feel free to disable the eslint warning
   - if you want to keep fetching in 200ms intervals so long as the consumer is mounted:

```js
  // StockPriceProvider
  ...
    fetch: useCallback(() => dispatch({type: 'fetch', payload: 200}), [])
  ...
  // StockPriceConsumer
  ...
    useEffect(() => {
      const i = setInterval(fetch, 200)
      return () => clearInterval(i)
    }, [fetch])
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The important concept here is that react compares the objects by reference equality. Meaning that every time the reference (and not the content) changes it will trigger a re-render. As a rule of thumb, you always need to define objects/functions that you want to pass to child components by `useCallback` and `useMemo`.

So in your case:
The fetch function will become:

```
const fetch = useCallback(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        dispatch({ type: 'fetch', payload: 200 });
    }, 1000);
}, []);
```

The empty array means that this function will be only defined when the component is mounted. And then:

```
let {val, fetch} = stockPrice;

 useEffect(() => {
    fetch();
 }, [val, fetch]);
```

This means the useEffect's callback will execute only when `fetch` or `val` changes. Since `fetch` will be defined only once, in practice it means only `val` changes are gonna trigger the effect's callback.

Also, I can imagine you want to trigger the fetch only when `isNaN(val)` so:

```
let {val, fetch} = stockPrice;

 useEffect(() => {
    if(isNaN(val)) {
        fetch();
    }
 }, [val, fetch]);
```

All that being said, there's a bigger issue with this code!

You should reconsider the way you use `setTimeout` since the callback can run when the component is already unmounted and that can lead to a different bug. In these cases you should `useEffect` and clear any async operation before unmounting the component. So here's my suggestion:

```
import React, { useCallback, useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
interface StockPrice {
    val: number;
    setFetched: () => void;
}

const initialStockPrice = { val: NaN, setFetched: () => { } };

type Action = {
    type: string;
    payload: any;
};

const stockPriceReducer = (state: StockPrice, action: Action): StockPrice => {
    if (action.type === 'fetch') {
        return { ...state, val: action.payload };
    }
    return { ...state };
};

const myContext = React.createContext<StockPrice>(initialStockPrice);

const StockPriceProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(
        stockPriceReducer,
        initialStockPrice
    );
    const setFetched = useCallback(() => {
        dispatch({ type: 'fetch', payload: 200 });
    }, []);
    const contextVal = {
        ...state,
        setFetched,
    };
    return <myContext.Provider value={contextVal}>{children}</myContext.Provider>;
};

const StockPriceConsumer: React.FC = () => {

    const stockPrice = useContext(myContext);
    const {val, setFetched} = stockPrice;

    useEffect(() => {
        let handle = -1;
        if(isNaN(val)) {
            let handle = setTimeout(() => { // Or whatever async operation
                setFetched();
            }, 200);
        }
        return () => clearTimeout(handle); // Clear timeout before unmounting.
    }, [val, setFetched]);
    return <h1>{stockPrice.val.toString()}</h1>;
};
```